# Find different elements according to different criteria using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like using the `findAll()` function of the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) Python library, find several elements in an HTML. These elements must meet several criteria, but independently.

For example, suppose that my object looks like this:

```
<div class="my_class">
    <span class="not_cool">
        <p name="p_1">A</p>
        <p name="p_2">B</p>
    </span>
    <span class="cool">
        <p name="p_3">C</p>
    </span>
</div>
```

And I want to find every `span` of `class="cool"`  and every `p` with `name="p_1"` (here there is only one of each, but imagine that this is not the case).

Individually, I will do:

```
.findAll("span",attrs={"class":"cool"})
.findAll("p",attrs={"name":"p_1"})
```

In a perfect world, I would like to do:

```
.findAll([
        ["span",attrs={"class":"cool"}],
        ["p",attrs={"name":"p_1"}]
    ]}
```

But of course, it does not work like this.

Actually, I try to make a function that translates HTML to BBCode (I do not want and can not use an existing one).
So, I need to keep only some tag that interest me.

However, I must also know the order of these elements. If I use two different `.findAll()`, I will not know what is before what, and what is after what.

Does anyone have a solution please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to use a search function:

```
.find_all(lambda t: (t.name == 'span' and 'cool' in t['class']) or
                    (t.name == 'p' and t.get('name') == 'p_1'))
```

A callable argument will be passed each tag object in the tree; if the callable returns `True` it is included. The above `lambda` tests if the tag name matches and if a specific attribute is there.  The `class` attribute is special in that when present, it is always parsed out to a list.

Note that for BeautifulSoup 4, the camel-case function names have been deprecated; the lower_case_with_underscore names are the canonical methods. If you are still using BeautifulSoup 3, you probably want to upgrade. Version 3 has not seen updates in over 2 years now.

Comment: @That1Guy: Yes, BeautifulSoup 3 also supports callables for searching.

Comment: @That1Guy: however, know that BeatifulSoup 3 is *long* outdated. It hasn't seen new releases for more than 2 years now.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. I only ask because it would appear that the OP is using BeautifulSoup 3 (findAll vs find_all).

Comment: @That1Guy: BeautifulSoup 4 also supports the BS3 camelcase methods, a lot of tutorials still use those too for some reason, so it's never safe to assume.

Comment: I didn't realize that, thanks for the correction. In any case +1. Your answer is more correct than mine, however I'll leave mine up as an alternative for cases where iteration is preferred.

Comment: I just wanted to add, if someone or myself back here, that the function will take twice a searched item if it is in another part wanted (if I am looking for `class=my_class` and `name=p_1` for example). To prevent this, simply set the filter function recursively through parent elements until `t.parent==None` (meaning that every parents node has been treated without finding tag satisfactoring the filtering function, so our primary target element will not be duplicated). The function looks like: http://pastebin.com/L3XAdDcG It may not be the most effective method but it is the only one I found.

Answer (score 1):

Simply find all children of each `span` with that particular class by iterating over all desired `spans`.

```
spans = soup.findAll("span",attrs={"class":"cool"})
for span in spans:
    ps = span.findAll("p",attrs={"name":"p_1"})
```

Comment: My example is perhaps not perfect. Suppose that `p` is outside the `span` and I still want to get it, your code will not work.